# Where to find Vista's service pack level?

Tags: windows-vista, service-pack

When Vista's service pack version is at level 1 (SP1), [this version number is shown at "Control Panel / System"](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/ht/srvpackvista.htm). However, on my system this information has disappeared, probably because I'm now using SP2. I'd like to verify this, so I can be certain.

**Conclusion**: Thanks to [Ivo](https://superuser.com/users/1548/ivo) I found the registry settings that store the service pack version number. Because I was (incorrectly) convinced that I had installed a service pack already, and because the "CSDBuildNumber" was 2 on my system, I did some research about the info in the registry. Here are the results:

Fresh Windows Vista image without SP:

- CSDBuildNumber: 2
- CSDVersion is not present

Fresh Windows Vista image with SP1:

- CSDBuildNumber: 1616
- CSDVersion: Service Pack 1

Fresh Windows Vista image with SP2:

- CSDBuildNumber: 1621
- CSDVersion: Service Pack 2

So indeed, my problem was that - contrary to what I believed - I had no service pack installed. Thus, **the "Control Panel / System" dialog can be trusted**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this registry entry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\CSDBuildNumber

[Check this article](http://blogs.dirteam.com/blogs/sanderberkouwer/archive/2007/11/02/how-to-determine-your-windows-server-2008-version.aspx) on what it's for (thanks for the comments)

Comment: Jep! The service pack version can be found at: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\CSDBuildNumber". Please update you're answer, and I'll "accept" it.

Comment: For completeness sake, I found the CSDBuildNumber-means-service-pack-level confirmation at: http://blogs.dirteam.com/blogs/sanderberkouwer/archive/2007/11/02/how-to-determine-your-windows-server-2008-version.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. In the end, my conclusion is that I don't have a service pack installed.

Comment: After completing my own tests, the "CSDBuildNumber = 2" seems to mean that no service packs are installed. Instead, the "CSDVersion" field contains the SP version (as a string), but this field doesn't exist if no service packs are installed.

Answer (score 3):

Run `winver` from the start menu type-in box (or anywhere else you can run arbitrary commands from).

This little util opens up a message box that lists the current Windows version and service pack level.

Comment: Hmmm that seems to work, though on Windows 7 off course there's no line mentioning a lack of a "service pack"...

Comment: On my system, the popup dialog merely says: "version 6.0 (Build 6000)". No service pack version is mentioned :s

Comment: @lvo: Correct. If there is no service pack installed, no service pack is listed in the version info (rather than it explicitly stating "no service pack").

Comment: @Dimitry: Then no service pack is installed (or something is wrong and the utility can't see the fact that a service pack has in fact been installed). The machine I'm currently on reports Version 6.0 (Build 6002: Service Pack 2), and carries the Vista logo in the top image of the box.

Comment: Thanks for your remark that I don't have a service pack installed. It appeared to be correct :-)

Answer (score 2):

My answer (the *right* answer), for posterity:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows\CSDVersion (a REG_DWORD)
```

The Service Pack level (if any) value is obtained by doing `CSDVersion >> 8` i.e. right-shifting the CSDVersion REG_DWORD by 8 bits; e.g. the REG_DWORD *value* will be `0x100` for SP1, `0x200` for SP2, and so on.

This works for Windows versions all the way back to NT4, and **is Microsoft's preferred way of obtaining SP level** before the introduction of the [**OSVERSIONINFOEX** structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms724833.aspx), as outlined in the [Windows Fundamental Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954375.aspx) [1], specifically requirement "**7. Perform Windows Version-Checking Correctly**" (see reference link below for more details)

[1] Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954375.aspx